# What is wrong here with my List?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I work in Eclipse. And it doesn't like a lil' part of this code. Eclipse says that in this part `someHashMap.keys()` `keys` is wrong.

```
final List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(someHashMap.keys());
```

So, what is wrong here with my `List`?

Comment: Ctrl + space dude... it's you friend till learning the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `keySet()`. `keys()` isn't a valid method for the `HashMap` class.

If you are trying to set the initial capacity of the array list, you can also do:

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(someHashMap.keySet().size());
```

Comment: He's obviously trying to initialize the contents of the `ArrayList`.